# Managing null values in variants using Delphi

Tags: delphi, null, delphi-xe, variants

I'm working with a COM component which exposes a lot of `Variant` properties, but sometimes these values are null. When I try to convert these values to string (or another Delphi type) the application raises an exception like this:

> Could not convert variant of type (Null) into type (String)

But if I use .net to call the same properties and the values are null, no exceptions are raised and the null values are treated as empty strings.

My question there is a way to handle these null values from Delphi avoiding these exceptions?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Try setting [NullStrictConvert](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/Variants.NullStrictConvert) to False.

As it's a global variable I use it like follows to minimize side effects:

```
var
  OldNullStrictConvert: Boolean;
begin
  OldNullStrictConvert := NullStrictConvert;
  NullStrictConvert := False;
  try
    // code containing conversions
  finally
    NullStrictConvert := OldNullStrictConvert;
  end;
end;
```

(In reality I have made a guardian interface out of this.)

NB: Where it's feasible I prefer code like [Warren](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5940957/managing-null-values-in-variants-using-delphi/5943476#5943476)'s.

Comment: @user422039: I love `strict` but how is it connected to Salvador's problem?

Comment: i believe what Salvador's problem interconnects keyboard, chair and ignored documentation (see my answer, second link is very verbose on Null and NullStrictConvert).

Comment: -1 Being a global variable, `NullStrictConvert` is not thread-safe, so setting it can have unwanted side effects in multi-threaded apps.

Answer (score 20):

The accepted answer changes a global setting, and could have unintended side effects on the operation of other code that was working before you changed it.

First you could just use `VarToStrDef`, secondly, if you must provide some functionality other than that, then I would have my code call my own function MyVarToStr, and do it like this:

```
resourcestring
    SNilValue = '[nil]';


function VarIsAssigned(v:Variant):Boolean; inline;
begin
          result := (v<>Variants.Null) and (not VarIsNull(V));
end;


function MyVarToStr( v:Variant):String;
begin
  if VarIsAssigned(v) then
    result := VarToStr(v)
else
    result := SNilValue;
end;
```

Since it seems that VarToStrDef should be enough, I only mean to demonstrate that it's better to write your code and call your own code, than to try to "globally change" the default behaviour of VCL/RTL library code.

Comment: Indeed. When possible I prefer solutions similar to your's. But sometimes the conversion is buried deep in library code you have no control over.

Comment: Oh yea. That's a helper in one of my personal-standard-library functions. added a definition.

Answer (score 14):

This is a documented behaviour of [`VarToStr`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/Variants.VarToStr) function. There is no need to reinvent a wheel.

Null variant is distinct type (yes, it is a type, not merely a value), which denotes either missing or **unknown** data. So, **strictly** speaking, regular variant *dynamic-typing* should not happen with `Null` values ([illustrated](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Variant_Types#Variants_in_Expressions) and reflected in RTL defaults).

#### given:

```
var
  V: Variant;
  S: string;
```

#### better code

```
S := VarToStr(V);             { stongly-typed explicit conversion }
```

#### relatively good code

```
if not VarIsNull(V) then      { program knows what it does, but reproduces RTL behaviour }
  S := V
else
  S := NullAsStringValue;
```

#### bad code

```
NullStrictConvert := False;   { smelly, from now on Null variant loses its specifics }
S := V;
```

#### even worse code

```
try
  S := V;
except on Eaten: Exception do { stinky PHP-style, hiding error instead of fixing it }
  S := NullAsStringValue;
end;
```

**NOTE:** Most late Delphi.NET exhibits exactly the same behaviour on Null variants, so OP's remark about .NET is questionable.

Answer (score 9):

`VarToStr()` and `VarToStrDef()` are the correct and proper way to convert a Null `Variant` to a `String`, as they explicitially check for Null values internally.

Answer (score 4):

..from user422039 code use VarToStr otherwise S:=V relays on an implicit conversion which may create different result on different environment:

```
S := VarToStr(V);
or
S := VarToStrDef(V, yourdefaultvalue);
```